# flyway - how to backup table before migration

Tags: flyway

How can I take backup of tables before flyway migrates the table in oracle.?

I want to make sure table DDL are captured before new script gets executed

Comment: Are you hoping to backup the data in the table or just the DDL definition of the table? And why do you need to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't you just issue a backup command from whatever tool, process, or command line you're using to issue the Flyway deploy command from?